# std::set of boost::weak_ptr<T> - Getting const_iterator to const T?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, weak-ptr

I have class containing an `std::set` of `boost::weak_ptr<T>`. I have two functions begin() and end() that return an iterator to the container. However, I don't want clients to be able to modify `T`. Simply returning a `const_iterator` won't work, because the `T` pointed to by the `boost::weak_ptr` will be editable.

What I want to do is return a `const_iterator` to `std::set<boost::weak_ptr<T const> >`. Casting from `std::set<boost::weak_ptr<T> >::const_iterator` does not work. Is there any way to get the behaviour I want?

Comment: Your these two statements seem contradictory : 1) *I don't want clients to be able to modify T* and 2) *because the T pointed to by the boost::weak_ptr will be editable.*. What does it mean?

Comment: @Nawaz What I mean is: returning a `const_iterator` to `std::set<boost::weak_ptr<T> >` makes it so that the client can not modify the `weak_ptr`. He can, however, still get a `shared_ptr<T>` from it and then modify `T` at will. Which is exactly what I don't want happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a *transform iterator* to convert the `weak_ptr<T>` to a `weak_ptr<const T>`.  Since you're already using Boost, you can use `boost::transform_iterator`:

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>

#include <set>

// Functor to transform a weak_ptr<T> to a weak_ptr<const T>
template <typename T>
struct make_weak_ptr_const
    : std::unary_function<boost::weak_ptr<T>, boost::weak_ptr<const T> >
{
    boost::weak_ptr<const T> operator()(const boost::weak_ptr<T>& p) const
    {
        return p;
    }
};

struct S { };

// Container demonstrating use of make_weak_ptr_const:
struct my_awesome_container
{
    typedef std::set<boost::weak_ptr<S> > BaseSet;
    typedef BaseSet::const_iterator       BaseIterator;

    typedef boost::transform_iterator<
                make_weak_ptr_const<S>, 
                BaseIterator
            > iterator;

    iterator begin() const 
    {
        return TransformedIterator(data.begin());
    }

    iterator end() const
    {
        return TransformedIterator(data.end());
    }

    std::set<boost::weak_ptr<S> > data;
};
```

If you don't want to use `boost::transform_iterator`, it is a straightforward task to write your own.  I showed how to do this in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467000/is-there-a-java-map-keyset-equivalent-for-cs-stdmap/5099345#5099345).

Comment: Thank you, I had no clue such a function existed. This is perfect!