# std::set_difference is it possible to compare set and map Keys?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

So we get a new set of strings, and we have one as map Keys. And we want to do `one way` set_difference (note - not set_symmetric_difference). So currently I have such ugly code like:

```
    std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<some_class> > _ds;
std::set<std::string> compare_and_clean(std::set<std::string> &new_)
{
    std::set<std::string> result;
    std::set<std::string> old;

    for (std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator mi = _ds.begin(); mi != _ds.end(); ++mi)
        old.insert(mi->first);

    std::set_difference( old.begin(), old.end(), new_.begin(), new_.end(), inserter(result, result.begin()));

    for (std::set<std::string>::iterator i = result.begin(); i != result.end(); ++i) {
        _ds.erase(*i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I wonder how to do set_difference over map Keys and set in more clean way?

Comment: "I upvote to everyone who tried to answer on to my question as soon as I find real answer and mark it as correct one." Please upvote only useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:  You can iterate over just the keys of the `std::map` using a transform iterator.

You can find two implementations of such a transform iterator (one using Boost, the other standalone) in [an answer I provided to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467000/is-there-a-java-map-keyset-equivalent-for-cs-stdmap/5099345#5099345).