# How to apply transform to an STL map in C++

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, lambda, transform

In C++, I'm using transform to change all the values of a map to uppercase.

```
  std::map<std::string, std::string> data = getData();

  // make all values uppercase
  std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),
         [](std::pair<std::string, std::string>& p) {
           boost::to_upper(p.second);
           return(p);
         });
```

This gives me the following compilation error:

```
/opt/local/include/gcc46/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4805:2: error: no match for call to '(main(int, char**)::<lambda(std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >&)>) (std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >&)
```

I think there's something wrong with the type of the argument in my lambda expression. It's probably something simple, but I can't seem to figure out what's expected.

Comment: Rather than assume a container stores a particular type. You can access the type information via value_type. `std::map<std::string, std::string>::value_type`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are missing the const in the first type of the pair.

```
[](std::pair<const std::string, std::string>& p) {
```

However this is not your problem: You cannot use a `map` as the OutputIterator, as they do not support assignment. You can, however mutate the second argument using `std::for_each`.

Good old `map_to_foobar`:

```
std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), 
              [](std::pair<const std::string, std::string>& p) {
                p.second = "foobar";
              });
```

Conceptual stuff: Calling `transform` with the same range as input and output is quite legit and makes a lot of sense if all your functors return by value and don't mutate their arguments. However, mutating something in place can be a faster (or at least look faster in code, nevermind the optimizing compiler) and makes a lot of sense with member functions.

Comment: Adding a const gives me another error /opt/local/include/gcc46/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:156:2: error: passing 'const std::basic_string<char>' as 'this' argument of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `std::transform` with a transform iterator.  For example, my `key_iterator`, posted in [an answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467000/is-there-a-java-map-keyset-equivalent-for-cs-stdmap/5099345#5099345), can be trivially converted into a `value_iterator`.  Then you'd end up with `std::transform(begin_values(data), end_values(data), begin_values(data), [](std::string s) { boost::to_upper(s); return s; });`.  In this case, I'd suggest `std::for_each`, though, because it eliminates the unnecessary copy.

Comment: Boost offers the range adaptor `boost::adaptors::map_values` which does the trick. Including the unnecessary copy of course.

Answer (score 12):

If you plan on sticking to `std::transform`, then you need [`std::inserter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter):

**C++03 MCVE**

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> Map;

struct ToUpper
{
    Map::value_type & operator()(Map::value_type & pair) const
    {
        boost::to_upper(pair.second);
        return pair;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Map m;
    m[0] = "snake_case";
    m[1] = "camelCase";
    m[2] = "PascalCase";
    
    std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::inserter(m, m.end()), ToUpper());
    
    for (Map::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

---

**C++11** (you can do everything in `main()` really)

```
int main()
{
    auto m = getData();

    auto toUpper = [] (decltype(m)::value_type & pair)
    {
        boost::to_upper(pair.second);
        return pair;
    };

    std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::inserter(m, m.end()), toUpper);

    for (auto const & pair : m)
        std::cout << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << std::endl;
}
```

---

**C++14** (you can use `auto` in lambda parameters)

```
int main()
{
    auto m = getData();

    auto toUpper = [] (auto & pair)
    {
        boost::to_upper(pair.second);
        return pair;
    };
    std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::inserter(m, m.end()), toUpper);

    for (auto const & pair : m)
        std::cout << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << std::endl;
}
```

---

**C++17** (just because i love structured bindings)

```
int main()
{
    auto m = getData();

    auto toUpper = [] (auto & pair)
    {
        boost::to_upper(pair.second);
        return pair;
    };
    std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::inserter(m, m.end()), toUpper);

    for (auto const & [key, value] : m)
        std::cout << key << ", " << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you are not using structured binding within a transform `UnaryOp`. Your description for C++17 is misleading.

Comment: update for C++ ranges?